# How is the following scenario tested with a unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Would I unit test the following or do some other kind of test:

I want to update a value in a database and after updating the value, I want to make sure the database was updated with the correct value, but this means I have to query the database and determine if the correct value is there and I thought in unit testing, touching the database is a NO-NO.

I would want to unit test a method like the following (db and Update are made up):

```
public void UpdateValue(int value)
{
   db.Update(value);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to test any logic in your UpdateValue method, OR do you want to test that your call makes it to the database and that the record in the database reflects the update? From a testing perspective this impacts how to write your tests.

Comment: Both actually, I want to test if UpdatValue was called successfully and i want to test if the actual value passed to UpdateValue ended up in the db and not some other value.

Comment: THen you probably need 2 testing scenarios - a unit test (with a mock to remove the real db call) and another test that sets and retrieves the value in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply test that your method successfully makes the call to the database. Mocking tends to focus on this, that the calls you expect to happen actually *do* happen.

It would involve replacing `db` with a test version such that your test of `UpdateValue` would assert that it expects `db.Update(value)` to be called with the same value.

Testing stored procedures or SQL should be done (at the end of the day, it is still subject to the same possibility of error that C# code is), but would likely be done independently of your code unit tests. We have a separate test project for testing stored procedure logic. As this involves a physical database, it is kept separate and minimal - but we still see it as essential. We have got to the stage where almost all database script is tested, but to begin with you can usually get away with not testing basic CRUD code. Any SQL that features conditional statements get tested.

If you want to do an end-to-end test to see if you can use your code to save to the database and get a value back again, this ***isn't*** a unit test by definition. As [@lazyberezovsky states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10916291/358221), this is an *integration* test. Unit tests aim to remove all dependencies around a unit of code in order to test that unit alone.

That said, it is imperative (in my opinion) to have integration tests also. We have them against use cases, such that we test what the user has signed off on as a use case action. This hammers a lot of code in one go, but has the distinct *disadvantage* of struggling against shared state / side-effecting code. You find that with integration tests, the bulk of the test is preparation instead of assertion of the code. You also find that they don't identify specific code that fails, so diagnosing integration test failures is harder.

We strike a middle ground with our integration tests. Our database is fed through a DAL interface, we simply stub this interface (different to mocking) in order to provide in-memory test data as opposed to a physical database. The one downside with this is we miss integration tests over the database proper.

Comment: OK, so I am clear on what you are saying, the unit test should just focus on if there was a successful connection and using a Mocking framework would actually help in determining if the correct value was stored in the db.  How do I truly know if the db was updated with the correct value unless I query it?  Does mocking do this as well?

Comment: What do you mean by testing stored procs or SQL independently of code?  And is it still done with unit tests?  Do you have an example?

Comment: @Xaisoft If there is more custom code between your value and the database (as in, SQL or stored procedure code) that is more than a very simple CRUD action, I would test it separately, but I would still test it.

Comment: @Xaisoft Not off-hand. We were doing this when there weren't many tools around we thought could help, so we simply have some unit tests that hard-code values to the sprocs for the various code paths we expect them to take and query the results manually. Testing DAL logic and testing database logic should be separate. If you test that your DAL successfully _sends_ the data and that your database successfully saves it, even if done separately you have proven your system.

Comment: No it is a simple CRUD action, but I am sort of paranoid that the actual value is would not be updated, for example, while updated, the value would get corrupted before it hit the database and some other value would get updated.

Comment: @Xaisoft That is the responsibility of the database provider to test that. It is usually safe to assume that a database can save values given no intervention from your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Responsibility of your object is passing value to it's dependency (which is database). So, inject some abstraction, which represents database to your object:

```
public Foo(IDatabase db)
{
   _db = db;
}
```

and verify interaction between this dependency and object you are testing:

```
Mock<IDatabase> db = new Mock<IDatabase>();
db.Setup(x => x.Update(5));
Foo foo = new Foo(db.Object);
foo.Update(5);
db.VerifyAll();
```

And you are right, touching the database *in unit test* is a NO-NO. Unit test should verify behavior of only one unit (in isolation). If you want to check several units working together (your foo and db), then you need an *integration test* which will verify data actually changed in database.

UPDATE: [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) framework is used in this sample.

Comment: Good call on the integration tests, which are still useful if a little more involved to code.

Comment: Can you explain the code above and what mocking framework is this?  Thanks

Comment: @Xaisoft I'm not sure what framework it is, but the important part is the `IDatabase` interface. This allows a mocking framework to implement the interface with a version that can track method calls. Your consuming code (`UpdateValue`) doesn't care how the `IDatabase` is implemented, just that it adheres to the contract. This means you can _inject_ a different implementation for unit test support and not compromise the validity of the test over your code. Mocking frameworks are not _required_, they just do a lot of the plumbing for you automagically.

Comment: Its `moq` framework. With any mocking framework you can easily mock abstractions (e.g. interfaces). So, when you make your class depend on abstraction, you can easily mock that abstraction, provide some fake data for your tests, and verify interaction between you object and mock. In code above mocked database passed to foo object. Then foo is exercised by calling it's `Update` method. And last part is verification of interaction - we check that your foo object actually called his mock and passed correct parameter to it.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, a test that touches a database is not a "unit test" but an "integration test", according to purist definition.

The typical answer is to replace the call to db.Update() with a mock, but in some cases you may feel that you are not testing enough of your code if you do that.

Depending on what database you're using, there may be another option. If you use SQL Server, your unit tests can be executed against a local file SQL Express db. That file can be overwritten with the original clean copy upon every unit test execution, so that your tests become very repeatable too. All you need to do is deploy the SQL Express database with your unit test code, and set the connection string to that local db in your unit test app.config.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember that unit tests are not perfect remedy for all automated software testing.

Situation you described is usually tested in two ways:

- First, you do unit test as a part of regular development, and this test would simply ensure that dependency was called with appropriate values (as explained in Adam Houldsworth and lazyberezovsky answers). This simply tells you (and other developers) that *this code does that, and here's proof*.
- Next, you do integration test. This test requires real components and appropriate setup (as in, valid configuration, no/minimal number of mocks). This test shows that your components (or application as a whole) work and interact under real-world scenario.

Each of those types of testing has its place, and you usually want to have both of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use a more specific example, because it'll be easier to talk about. Let's say that `UpdateValue` is actually somewhere in a retail system, updating an old price with a new value in cents.

Perhaps your class is responsible for providing current prices or historical prices - let's call it a `PriceProvider`. Maybe it knows about how to provide a refund price for a receipt. Maybe it knows how to give a range of prices for white coloured fridge-freezers. It also knows how to update prices with a new one provided in pence. If that's its job then it shouldn't know where the prices are stored, because it already has one responsibility (single responsibility principle). It should delegate the responsibility of retrieving prices to something else, and its job is to translate the business requests into parameterised calls to something that knows where the prices are stored.

Or, maybe your class is responsible for retrieving prices from and updating prices to the database - a `DatabasePriceRepository`. It knows how to look up a price for a date and an item, or to get a list of prices for a date and a category, but it doesn't care why you're looking it up. If this is your class, it's coupled strongly to the database - that's its sole responsibility - and so there's no point mocking that bit out, or the class will have no value. Instead you can test it by doing integration tests or by writing full-stack scenarios or even by testing it manually.

I've worked in projects where we used Hibernate and tested the config files by instantiating different objects. We wired Hibernate up to an in-memory database to do it. That was very fast and gave us really quick feedback! I've also worked in places where we had end-to-end scenarios from UI to the database, more where we tested some service by hitting it with HTTP requests and checking the response, and others where we tested this manually.

Regardless of whether you unit test *this* class, at some point you have to touch the database in production, and I'm sure you'll want to test that before you go live. If you unit test this class, you'll need to perform an integration test somewhere else, automated or otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Can you explain how you would go about using in-memory database? I am using .NET, so I assume i would use NHibernate or something similar?

Comment: If you're on a large Enterprise project, it's common to use something like NHibernate with Oracle or SQL Server in production. For testing, you would still use NHibernate, but you'd set it up with a different connection string and use your in-memory database instead. This might help: http://ayende.com/blog/3983/nhibernate-unit-testing (it's not really unit testing, but it's still fast).